# Can't connect using SSH while using Ansible, but command prompt works just fine

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

### Problem

I'm trying to connect to a few of my **Linux EC2 Instances** and I'm getting this weird behavior depending on how I'm connecting to it.

#### Terminal

If I try to connect to it from the terminal using the following command:

```
ssh -i "<PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE>" ec2-user@<PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS>
```

I'm able to connect successfully.

#### Visual Studio Code Remote Explorer

I am able to connect to the instance successfully.

#### Paramiko

```py
# Create a new connection.
ssh_conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Load the Private Key.
my_rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(key_file)

# Connect to the server.
_session = ssh_conn.connect(
    hostname=host,
    port=port,
    username=username,
    pkey=my_rsa_key,
    timeout=5
)
```

Here I get a timeout error. Here I'm confident the code is fine because it works with some instances but not others and the issue seem to always be the connection portion.

#### Ansible

When I try to connect to the same EC2 instance using Ansible I get `Permission denied (publickey)`. Now I can confidently say it's not a syntax error inside of the Ansible code because when I run the same code on a few different EC2 instances it runs fine without problem. The issue is only related to the connection process.

### Thoughts?

The behavior is limited to a few instances and it's always the same issue. What would cause behavior like this or how could I go about trying to diagnose the problem? I'm happy to add more detail but I wanted to start here and see what people thought.

Comment: Do you have ansible group vars setting `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` (or `ansible_user`) to a different value for some instances?

Answer (score 1):

This error (publickey.) basically means that Ansible has no idea which remote user it should connect to. That's why it works when you explicitly call ssh command and doesn't using Ansible or other tools.

Regarding Ansible, add this line of code into the inventory file:

```
your_host_group:
  vars:
    ansible_user: ec2-user
  hosts:
    your_hostname:
```